# What's the problem?: "read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fillna'"

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('file name', fillna=0, header = 0)
```

The error comes out like this below.

```
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fillna'
```

How to solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

There is used bad argument, I guess you want chain after `read_excel` for convert all missing values to `0`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file name', header = 0).fillna(0)
```

Comment: But the book said that df = pd.read_excel('file name', fillna=0, header = 0) is fine. It is working at others' laptops, but not mine. Why?

Comment: @PhilliP - What book? How old is this book? Book is online?

Comment: @PhilliP - What is your pandas version?

Comment: it's 2019s. Is this because of the difference of pandas version?

Comment: hmmm, never heard/use this argument in `read_excel`, so I am surprise it working.

Comment: @PhilliP - Is this book online?

Comment: No, it's printed. It's one of the famous books written in Korean.

Comment: Wau, I never use it. If working for all people but for you not, it seems some different versions of pandas.

Comment: I guess so... should check other books on pandas

Comment: @PhilliP - What is name of this book? I can try to find it.

Comment: Python Machine Learning Pandas Data Analytics(파이썬 머신러닝 판다스 데이터 분석)